# C-b <left/right> key not switching panes in tmux

Tags: tmux

Problem: "C-b left/right" key combination is not switching between panes in tmux, it is resizing the pane.

tmux version: 1.8

OS: BackBox 4.4

Tried to find the 'tmux.conf' in the home directory or in the '/etc' folder, no success.

Archwiki says that left/right keys are for resizing panes. Ok, so if that's the case how ill I move between panes?

Answer (score 0):

`C-b-<left>` resizes the pane while `C-b <left>` switches pane. So you need to release `C-b` before pressing `<left>` to be able to do the switch.

Comment: Thanks, C-b then release then <left> works. Can you tell where "tmux.conf" file is located.

Comment: default places are `~/.tmux.conf` and system wide in `/etc/tmux.conf`. They probably don't exist if you haven't configured anything. Also - try `man tmux` to find answers to this kind of question.